# How to find max from strings with multiple decimals in python pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a data-frame with column entries like below. How can I find max value in such case ? The max value here I would consider ( though not true) is 5.0.5.658

```
4.6.0.2292
4.6.0.3122
4.8.0.1500
4.8.0.1938
5.0.4.283
5.0.5.658
```

Comment: What is max here? If use `max()` it not working?

Comment: @jezrael using max() on column gives . TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Comment: There maybe a blank value in column too.

Comment: So use `df['col'].dropna().max()`

Comment: Is `5.0.5.8` "bigger" than `5.0.5.658`? In other words, is your comparison numerical or lexicographical?

Comment: @DYZ , 5.0.5.8 is bigger than 6.0.5.658

Comment: @jezrael , df['col'].dropna().max() works. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Because you get error:

> TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

it means there are some missing values. So remove them by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and then get `max` for maximum by lexicographical sorting:

```
print (df['col'].dropna().max())
```

If necessary maximal value by numerical sorting:

```
idx = (df['col'].str.split('\.', expand=True)
                .astype(float)
                .sort_values(list(range(4)), ascending=False)
                .index[0])
print (df.loc[idx, 'col'])
```